datagridview cellvaluechanged not firing in Windows Forms
I have cellvaluechanged which does not fire, I tried alot of options and nothing is working:
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {


         if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns[6].Index && e.RowIndex > 0)
         {

             var selectedValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
             if (selectedValue != null)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("selectedValue" + selectedValue);
                 var currentDescription = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value?.ToString() ?? "";

                 currentDescription += " " + selectedValue;

                 dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = currentDescription;

                 context.SaveChanges();
             }
         }
     

 }

enter image description here
Every thing is Design is good and i checked the names and i can found any problem
I had en annen form and i used 3 tab with dataGridViews , First one worked for a while and then didn't fired
Thank you

I fix it, it was erverything right just should first seclect the row , then edit. Without secteting the row it do not work
